# Asp.net nested repeaters?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have Reviews section where each review has 1 or more comments. need to display comments bellow review using nested repeaters.

```
<asp:Repeater id="RepeaterReviews" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <b style="font-size:12pt;"><%#Eval("Username")%></b>
                                    <br />
                                    <b><%#Eval("Title")%></b>
                                    <br /><br />
                                </td>
                            </tr>   

                        <asp:Repeater id="RepeaterComment" runat="server"  >
                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                      <tr>
                                          <td colspan="3">
                                              <b style="font-size:12pt;"><%#Eval("Username")%></b>
                                              <br />
                                              <b><%#Eval("Comment")%></b>
                                              <br /><br />
                                          </td>
                                      </tr>   
                              </ItemTemplate>
                              </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
```

code behind

```
Sub ItemBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
             Dim ReviewID As Integer = CType(Eval("ReviewID"), Integer) 'doesn't work
          Dim drv As DataRowView = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
          Dim RepeaterComment As Repeater = CType(e.Item.FindControl("RepeaterComment"), Repeater)
end if
end sub
```

What I have is 1 to many relationship between Reviews and Comments. 
**How to  get `ReviewID` from first `RepeaterReviews` datasource ?**

Answer (score 0):

The technique you're using in your ItemBound method is pretty close.  You just need to use the Item Property on the DataRowView instance (drv) to get the value.

In this example I've skipped making the drv variable and have done it in a single line:

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

    Dim ReviewID As Integer = CInt(CType(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView).Item("ReviewID"))

    'Do what you want with the ReviewID

End If
```

Now all of that assumes you have a ReviewID field in the DataTable being bound to the Repeater.  If you don't, this won't work.  One other thing to note is that some adjustments will be required if you're binding a Generic List of a Custom Review Class like the following example:

```
Public Class Review
    Public Property ReviewID As Integer
    Public Property Username As String
    Public Property Title As String
End Class

Private Sub LoadData()

    Dim lstReviews As New List(Of Review)

    Dim objReview As New Review

    objReview.ReviewID = 1
    objReview.Title = "Test"
    objReview.Username = "User"

    lstReviews.Add(objReview)

    RepeaterReviews.DataSource = lstReviews
    RepeaterReviews.DataBind()  

End Sub
```

In this instance you'll have to alter your ItemBound code since the underlying data that is bound to the RepeaterItem is no longer a DataRowView, but rather a Review Class instance.

```
If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

    Dim ReviewID As Integer = CType(e.Item.DataItem, Review).ReviewID

    'Do what you want with the ReviewID

End If
```